# Cannot set property 'src' of null of images assets

Tags: javascript

I'm tying to display all images from folder assets
I have 1.png until 255.png

In index.html

```
  <img id="default_image" src="">
```

```
var default_image = document.getElementById('default_image');
for (var i = 1; i < 255; i++) {
  var default_img_src = "assets/" + i + ".png";
  default_image.src = default_img_src;
  document.body.appendChild(default_image);

}
```

So I try this but I got the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null
```

And I don't know how to solve it. How I can solve it ? thanks

Comment: What does your markup look like?

Comment: Where's the HTML showing the `default_image`?

Comment: Does your script lead or follow the markup?

Comment: `".png"` not `"png"`. And IDs **must** be unique

Comment: If I run your code as you show it above, I do not get the error `Cannot set property 'src' of null`.  Ignoring the other issue with your code, this error is unreproducable based on your example.

Comment: Yes thanks for .png but I still got the error

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues.

1. You are trying to get a single element and reassigning the source over and over again. You are going to want to create a new element for each.
2. You are missing the period before your file extension.

Try this:

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 255; i++) {
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "assets/" + i + ".png";
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

Here is an example:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    loadImages(5);
}

function loadImages(numImages) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= numImages; i++) {
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    //img.src = "assets/" + i + ".png";
    img.src = 'https://picsum.photos/100';
    img.className = 'default-image';
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  }
}
```

```css
.default-image {
   margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I got this : script.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Comment: Place this code inside the `onload` event of the window.